# How to fix 'Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires ...' error in java

Tags: java, android

I trie to open CustomTabsIntent from a Card i tried doing from an intent but i have the next error

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

This is the code of my app:
[image]
I expected to open a customtabinetnt with the url from de url, but th actual output is error

Comment: Hi there - please include all code directly in your question, and formatted as code - it makes it much easier to read / copy-paste / execute :)

Answer (score 2):

```
customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code for this:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                builder.addDefaultShareMenuItem();
                builder.setToolbarColor((R.color.colorPrimary));
                builder.setShowTitle(true);
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                CustomTabsHelper.addKeepAliveExtra(v.getContext(), customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                CustomTabsHelper.openCustomTab(v.getContext(),customTabsIntent,Uri.parse(url),new WebViewFallback());


        }
    } );
```

This is the correct code for made running the CustomTabsIntent from a viewholder.itemview